# nhibernate 3.0 Oracle connection through ODP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, connection, odp.net

Can someone tell me whats wrong with the nhibernate config below? Using the latest ODP.NET version.

```
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">DATA SOURCE=Oracle2;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=***;PASSWORD=*****</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9Dialect</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I get the following error

```
Error 1 Test 'ODPNETNH.Tests.GenerateSchema_Fixture.Can_generate_schema' failed: NHibernate.MappingException : Could not compile the mapping document: ODPNETNH.Mappings.Vendor.hbm.xml
  ----> NHibernate.HibernateException : Could not instantiate dialect class NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9Dialect
  ----> System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9Dialect. Possible cause: no assembly name specified.
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception)
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddDeserializedMapping(HbmMapping mappingDocument, String documentFileName)
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddValidatedDocument(NamedXmlDocument doc)
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ProcessMappingsQueue()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had quite a few problems working with NHibernate and Oracle (ODP.NET). 
At the end the only thing which worked for me was to reference Oracle.DataAccess.dll ver. **2.111**, specifying **Copy Local = true** for the DLL.
In my Nhibernate config I've used **Oracle10gDialect**.
Last but not least I've used this new connection-string style:

```
<property name="connection.connection_string">
      Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.1.1)(PORT=1522)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DIAP60FF)));User ID=myusername;Password=mypassword;</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Had to call Configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

Comment: Also, there is no dialect by NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9Dialect. It has to be NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9iDialect.

Comment: Deepfreezed, if you've found a solution, please, mark it as a accepted answer. It's how stackoverflow works! :)